# Picker view selection their parameter can passed on post method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uipickerview

I am new to IOS i want to show based on picker view selection in textfield their parameter can be passed as a Post method to getting response and viewed in alert view.

Picker view delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag == 2){
        return arrMsg.count;
    }else if(pickerView.tag == 1){
    return currencyname1.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return from_currency.count;
    }
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

{


    if(pickerView.tag == 2){
        return [arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
    }else if(pickerView.tag == 1){
        return [currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        return [from_currency objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}


- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag ==2){
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);
    }else if(pickerView.tag ==1){
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id1 objectAtIndex:row]);

    }
    else
    {
        currency2.text = (NSString *)[from_currency objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id2 objectAtIndex:row]);
    }




}
```

viedidload:

Array created :

```
 arrMsg = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.branch_name"];
        //NSLog(@"%@",json);
        arrmsg1 =[json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.id"];
        firststr = [arrmsg1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        currencyname1 = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.currency_name"];
        id1 = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.id"];

        from_currency = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.currency_name"];
        id2 = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.id"];
        secondstr = [id1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        thirdstr = [id2 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"%@",secondstr);
        NSLog(@"%@",thirdstr); 

    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&from_curr=%@&to_curr=%@&value=%@",firststr,secondstr,thirdstr,fourthstr]; 



pktStatePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

pktStatePicker  .delegate = self;

pktStatePicker  .dataSource = self;
txtText.delegate = self ;
currency1.delegate = self;
currency2.delegate = self;
[ pktStatePicker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
```

Comment: show your arrMsg once

Answer (score 0):

> An NSNotificationCenter object (or simply, notification center) provides a mechanism for broadcasting information within a program.

You can read more about [NSNotificationCenter here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/).

One of the possibilities is send an object through the Notification Center. If you want send an object you have to call `postNotification` like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notification_name" object:self userInfo:@{@"result":arrMsg}];
```

You have to put this piece of code inside of the method that will return/pass your array.

Once you call `postNotification` you have to set an `observer` inside of the class that will get the object you have sent using `postNotification`.

And you can set the `observer` in `viewDidLoad` as follow:

```
// NSNotification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doSomething:)
                                             name:@"notification_name"
                                           object:nil];
```

When the `observer` inside of this class get your notification, it will call the `method` in `@selector`. This method (in the code above `doSomething:`) have to be defined in the class you set the `observer`.

```
-(void)doSomething:(NSNotification *) notification {

    // You can get the object you have sent - using the `notification` object
    NSMutableArray dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:notification.userInfo[@"result"]];
    // Do something else

}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Of course! See if it's more clear. Anything else just let me know.